# Значение выражения "как Тузик грелку"

Tags: перевод, выражения, idioms

> На «Автово» сумасшедший дом. Или был сумасшедший дом но с этой станцией вовсе ничего до конца не поймёшь. Только перед «Автово» ещё и «Кировский завод», а там есть «Кировская бригада», с которой не шути. Они безо всяких псов порвут, как Тузик **грелку**.

Я бы это перевел

> They will catch you without any dogs, just as (a dog's name) would catch a hot bottle.

Но этот перевод не имеет смысла. Как это правильно понять?

Comment: sorry, but questions about translations from Russian to English are off-topic here.

Comment: @shabunc So how else can I get to understand what the passage is about? I don't understand it's meaning. How else can I learn Russian if not by trying to understand?

Comment: @marmistrz - Просто отредактируйте вопрос, замените «перевести» на «понять», попросите объяснить, и вопрос снова откроют.

Comment: If you don't understant it's meaning it is  another thing. From the question it is not obvious. It looks like you understand but failing to translate.

Comment: Кстати, есть такой конкурс научно-фантастических рассказов — [Рваная грелка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это образное выражение означает, что кто-то (они, он, она) очень легко и быстро с кем-то ( с ними, с ним, с ней) совершит расправу, уничтожит. И сделает это так же легко и быстро, как собака порвёт на части медицинскую резиновую ёмкость для горячей воды, которую в России называют "грелка".

Эти слова не всегда являются грубой угрозой, довольно часто они имеют грубовато-иронический смысл.

This figurative expression means that someone (they, he, she) is very easy and fast with someone (them, him, her) to commit to kill, to destroy. And to make it as easy and fast as a dog will tear to pieces medical rubber hot water tank, which in Russia are called "грелка".".

These words are not always rude threat, they are often crudely ironic sense.

Answer (score 3):

"как Тузик грелку" — значит "на мелкие клочки".
Возможное переводы:
They will
make mincemeat of you/
tear you apart/
wipe the floor with you/
shred you into pieces
without any dogs.

*Upd*. Меня сейчас озарило. Собаки здесь не причем!

> They will make mincemeat of you without any mincer.

или

> They will shred you into pieces without any shredder.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще, выражение выглядит неоднозначным, так как грелки обычно делаются из довольно плотной резины, так что далеко не всякий "тузик" их способен порвать. Так что иногда употребляется вариант: "**Порвать как тузик тряпку**", что должно быть несколько более понятно.

Примерно то же самое означает и "Порвать на британский флаг" (to tear in pieces like Union Jack). Просто современный жаргон.